# Remove DOM element from websocket and node.js simple chat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom

I have created a very basic chat using websocket and node.js. Everything works fine. I now need to allow the users to delete their own messages in the chat by clicking on it.

In my research, I came across this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

I'm not entirely sure if that is the correct thing to use at all!

So lets say I have jQuery included in my page and I do something like:

```
$('.mychatelement').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Does the above code, remove the DOM only for the user that clicked on the element or will it remove the DOM for all the users in the chat?

Comment: `javascript/jQuery` is a client-side language so that will only remove the element for the client unless you send something to the server to then respond to all clients.

Comment: Ok, what can i send to the server?

Comment: Something unique of the element so the server and use that in the response to all clients to target the element for removal. Maybe an ID...

Comment: Ok, so if i use the id of the element and send that to the server, can i do something `$('#id of element').remove();` in my nodejs server?

Comment: No, you will want to send the ID from the server to all clients so you can run the `jQuery` in the clients browser.

Comment: Right, so basically, i send the id to server and then from the server to the users to remove that id?

Comment: That would be correct yes. It's like reversing the chat, rather than sending new chat data and appending to all clients you are sending an ID of existing chat data/element to all clients to be removed.